# How do I set angular build budgets for initial-es5 and initial-es2015 modules?

Tags: angular, build

When I build my Angular application I get the following budget warnings:

[image: Build Warnings]

I know I can adjust bugets in the angular.json file, but there doesn't seem to be a location for setting the initial project/module. Anyone know how to set the budget for the initial module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't know where to find the budgets for the initial-es2015 or initial-es5 modules. I had a project with 30 - 40 different libraries/projects, so my angular.json projects object was quite large. What confused me was that the error message didn't contain the project name. In the past, I have had libraries exceed their budgets, but the error message was clear. For example, consider the following message: "Exceeded maximum budget for nest-auth". The error clearly indicates the project with the budget issue. Whereas the initial-es2015 and initial-es5 error messages do not.

The budget that I needed to modify was the project I was running the build command on. For example consider the following command: ng build example-project. If a message is shown indicating that the initial-es2015 or initial-es5 modules have exceeded maximum budgets, the budget you want to edit is the project that is being built, which in this case in "example-project".

It seems like the error message could be improved. Aka "Exceeded maximum budget for example-project" instead of "Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es2015".

Another confirmation of the fix: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/bumping-angular-application-size-budgets-a223ad0cf34d

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the angular.json file for your project under "budgets"

Comment: There isn't an initial-es2015 project listed.

Comment: can you share you angular.json file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot as it is a private project. It was hard to interpret the error message, as I have 30-40 different project entries in angular.json. What confused me was that the error message didn't contain the project name. In the past, I have had libraries exceed their budgets, but the error message was clear. For example: "Exceeded maximum budget for nest-auth". The error message pointed me to the nest auth project in angular.json.